# How to get text from a primefaces component with selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, primefaces, automated-tests

I'm automating a system made in Primefaces and I'm having trouble finding elements.

**Case 1.**
I want to get the text of this span that is inside the **li**.

[I want to get the text circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmDNM.png)

I'm using this code. but I get the element not found error.

```
String textoErro = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"messagesCargoFuncaoCU\"]/div/ul/li[1]/span")).getText();
```

**Case 2.**
I want to get the contents of the **td**.

[I want to get the text circled in red. "AutomacaoTeste"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lVab.png)

I'm using this code.
But I get the error: Unable to locate element.

```
String textoName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dataTableAgfolhaCargoFuncao_data\"]/tr/td[3]/span")).getText();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector"

Comment: I would suggest you to use PrimeFaces-Selenium: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-selenium